# как создать сайт каталог и привязать к телеграм боту

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Нужно написать лотерейного бота, есть сайт, есть бот, есть часть кода с категориями каталога.

Данные о товарах каталога будут хранится как раз  на сайте, а бот будет обращаться к сайту и уже выводить соответствующее сообщение.

Как реализовать часть про связь бота с сайтом и загружать с помощью бота лоты в каталог?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй парсер на beautifulsoup4, и подключить его к боту.
Вот как примерно это выглядит на парсере сайта игр:

```
import telebot
import config

from telebot import types
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS


bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    sti = open('static/welcome2.webp', 'rb')
    bot.send_sticker(message.chat.id, sti)

#Keyboard
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    item1 = types.KeyboardButton("Страница 1")
    item2 = types.KeyboardButton("Сылки для этих игр")
    markup.add(item1, item2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                     "Добро пожаловать, {0.first_name}!\nЯ - <b>{1.first_name}</b>, бот созданный для просмотра страниц игр vsetop.".format(
                         message.from_user, bot.get_me()),
                     parse_mode='html', reply_markup=markup)

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def lalala(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if message.text == 'Страница 1':
            #PARSER
            config.log(message)
            max_page = 1
            pages = []

            for x in range(1, max_page + 1):
                pages.append(requests.get('https://vsetop.org/games/page/' + str(x) ) )

            for r in pages:
                html = BS(r.content, 'html.parser')

                for el in html.select('.news1'):
                    title = el.select('h1')
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, title[0].text)
                    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '<!-----------------!>')

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Детальнее с этой библиотекой вы можете ознакомиться в документации:
http://wiki.python.su/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8/BeautifulSoup